# How to annotate core Node.js modules with JSDoc to have code hinting in IntelliJ?

Tags: node.js, intellij-idea, jsdoc

So far I have a need for two of them, *util* and *fs*. Given a code like this:

```
var fs = require('fs');
var contents = fs.readFileSync('path/to/file', 'utf8');
```

Not only IntelliJ marks `readFileSync` as *Unresolved function or method*, but I am also devoid of, in my opinion, on of the best function given by IDEs - code hinting.

How can I annotate core Node.js functions with JSDoc to have code hinting and not have correct code erroneously marked as invalid?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Why core libraries are not resolved?

The issue with the invalid code is that you have "not NodeJS project".

You should install the NodeJS plugin: http://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/6098?pr=phpStorm

And then **create a new project** with the given sources.

IntelliJ will automatically overwrite the metadata and **hook the NodeJS environment** and all your core modules will be resolved.

### Why there is no code completion?

IntelliJ tries hard do determine the object signature, but some JS coding techniques prevent your IDE from reading the signature (it can be read *only in runtime*).

Regarding the type annotation you can have a look here, for example: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/scripted-dev/xFtPiBJDO4c

Update: I have written an article describing how you can enable the type hinting for NodeJS in IntelliJ IDEA: http://www.fse.guru/nodejs-autocomplete-in-idea-and-webstorm