# How to write JSDocs for npm config when its required in a module using webstorm?

Tags: javascript, annotations, comments, webstorm, jsdoc

**config/default.json**

```
{
    "somevar": "sometext" 
}
```

**SomeModule.js**

```
/**
 * From the configuration file
 * @typedef {Object} config
 * @property {string} somevar
 */

var config = require('config');

var someObject = {
    somevar: config.somevar // Webstorm doesn't know what this is!
};
```

Webstorm places a bumpy line under the somevar property of config. How can I have it not do that and actually recognize it with jsdocs?

Edit: This question is not a duplicate of [How to annotate core Node.js modules with JSDoc to have code hinting in IntelliJ?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23876604/how-to-annotate-core-node-js-modules-with-jsdoc-to-have-code-hinting-in-intellij)

Comment: works for me using your example - somevar is resolved. I'm using WS 9.0.3

Comment: D: well i guess i could reinstall webstorm

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to annotate core Node.js modules with JSDoc to have code hinting in IntelliJ?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23876604/how-to-annotate-core-node-js-modules-with-jsdoc-to-have-code-hinting-in-intellij)

Comment: Sorry, but this is not a duplicate, this refers to a specific node.js module called config. In intellij, it is inconsistent with other node.js modules. The other node.js modules, I have no problem with its hinting. Plus config is not a core module.